# ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames vs Setters?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Going through the default styling of control provided, I saw two very different syntax for doing very similar thing. Below is a screenshot of one of the example!

[image: XAML code]

Using ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames syntax, we are essentially setting the value of a property for a element, which can easily be achieved by Setter syntax as well in a **much more concise way**. Then why in all the default styling of controls, such syntax is used? Is it a legacy thing?

I can think of one benefit of ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames syntax over Setter syntax that it allows to change properties at some specific time using KeyTime property, but that is not used most of the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Largely it is a legacy thing. In Silverlight and WPF XAML, VisualStates can only use Storyboards for setting properties, and the Blend tooling at the time would also prefer creating Storyboards over using VisualStateSetters. For VisualStates if you don't need an animated state - which is most of the time - there's no real reason not to use Setters - it's usually more concise and easier to read. A lot of the more recently created controls in the framework or newly added states will use Setters over storyboards.

(And most of the time when you DO need animated states, what you're really looking for is actually animated State Transitions using VisualStateTransitions, not animated states themselves)